# How can i make my all my textbox not empty when i click the submit button

Tags: php, html

I'm new to PHP and I want to know How can i make my all my textbox not empty when i click the submit button. When i enter special characters like space,/;>< and etc all the textbox becomes empty. I only want that textbox that i input special characters to be empty not all the textbox.

HERE is my code

**function.php**

```
<html>
<head>
    <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
    </style>
</head>
<body> 
    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
    <form method="post" action="1.php"> 
         <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></span>
         <br><br>
         <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></span>
         <br><br>
         <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website"> <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['website'];?></span>
         <br><br>
         <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
         <br><br>
         <label>Gender:</label>
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
         <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
         <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['gender'];?></span>
         <br><br>
         <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
<?php 
unset($_SESSION['name']);
unset($_SESSION['email']);
unset($_SESSION['website']);
unset($_SESSION['comment']);
unset($_SESSION['gender']);
?>
```

**1.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
$nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
$name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";


if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
          {$_SESSION['name']= "Name is requiredassssssssssssssss";}
     }

     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email)) {
          {$_SESSION['email']= "email is requiredassssssssssssssss";}
     }

     $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$website)) {
          {$_SESSION['website']= "website is requiredassssssssssssssss";}
     }
}


function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

if ((!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) ||  (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email)) || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$website)))
{
    header("Location: function.php");
}

echo $_POST['name'];
echo $_POST['email'];
echo $_POST['website'];
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like this..

## function.php

```
        <html>
        <head>
        <style>
        .error {color: #FF0000;}
        </style>
        </head>
        <body> 


        <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
        <p><span class="error">* required field.</span></p>
        <form method="post" action="1.php"> 
           <label>Name:</label> <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['name_value'];?>" > <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['name'];?></span>
           <br><br>
           <label>E-mail:</label> <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['email_value'];?>"> <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['email'];?></span>
           <br><br>
           <label>Website:</label> <input type="text" name="website" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['website_value'];?>"> <span class="error"><?php echo $_SESSION['website'];?></span>
           <br><br>
           <label>Comment:</label> <input type="text" name="comment">
           <br><br>
           <label>Gender:</label>
           <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female
           <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male
           <span class="error">* <?php echo $_SESSION['gender'];?></span>
           <br><br>
           <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?php 
            unset($_SESSION['name']);
            unset($_SESSION['email']);
            unset($_SESSION['website']);
            unset($_SESSION['comment']);
            unset($_SESSION['gender']);
            unset($_SESSION['name_value']);
            unset($_SESSION['email_value']);
            unset($_SESSION['website_value']);
        ?>
```

## 1.php

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    $nameErr = $emailErr = $genderErr = $websiteErr = "";
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";


    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

         $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
         $_SESSION['name_value'] = $name;
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
              {
                 $_SESSION['name']= "Name is requiredassssssssssssssss";
                 $_SESSION['name_value']= "";
              }
         }


         $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
         $_SESSION['email_value'] = $email;
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email)) {
              {
                $_SESSION['email']= "email is requiredassssssssssssssss";
                $_SESSION['email_value']= "";
              }
         }

         $website = test_input($_POST["website"]);
         $_SESSION['website_value'] = $website;
         // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
         if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$website)) {
              {
                $_SESSION['website']= "website is requiredassssssssssssssss";
                $_SESSION['website_value']= "";                 
             }
         }


       }


    function test_input($data) {
       $data = trim($data);
       $data = stripslashes($data);
       $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
       return $data;
    }
     if ((!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) ||  (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$email)) || (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$website)))
    {
        header("Location: function.php");
    }

    echo $_POST['name'];
    echo $_POST['email'];
    echo $_POST['website'];
    ?>
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: is this making the textbox empty?